# Is it true that the only solutions are $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=x$?

Tags: functional-equations

Suppose that $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that

$$f(x^3+y^3)=f(x+y)((f(x-y))^2+f(xy)),$$ for all $x,y$ real numbers. Is it true that the only solutions are $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=x$? I did not come to any good result, but I think the solution should be difficult.

Comment: No, it is not true. There are two other constant solutions.

Comment: Let $f(x)=c$ be such that $c^2+c=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the constant functions $$f=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt 5}{2}$$ are both solutions.

Comment: How do we show that these are the only solutions?

Comment: @NoramSadir: That would be the next question!